# Exception class for forms

Tags: php, exception

Should form errors throw exceptions, for example if the username is incorrect, or password is wrong/too short .etc

I've used exceptions with forms, however when the exception is thrown only the exceptions is shown and not the form and which field the error occurred on, an excerpt from my exception class is as follows :

throw new InputException($field, $message);

e.g.
//username too short:

throw new InputException('username', 'Username must be 6 or more characters');

And then this message should appear underneath the username text field. The main thing I want is for the form to show when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions do not have to be thrown. For user interfaces, I will usually stack them.

Consider the following example (built in Zend Framework):

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

   protected $_exceptions = array();

   // Controller action, which displays a form
   public function indexAction() {
      $username = $this->_getParam('username');
      if (empty($username)) {
         $this->addException(
             new InvalidArgumentException('Username cannot be empty')
         );
      }
      // more handling code...
   }

   public function addException(Exception $e) {
      $this->exceptions[] = $e;
   }

   // executing just before displaying the user interface
   public function postDispatch() {
      // assign the exception stack to the view file
      $this->view->exceptions = $this->_exceptions;
      parent::postDispatch();
   }

}
```

You can still instanciate `Exception` classes without throwing them. In the example above, I stack them in the controller, and pass them to the view before displaying it. In the view, I can simply do:

```
if (!empty($this->exceptions)) {
   foreach ($this->exceptions as $exception) {
      // display something
   }
}
```

Of course, you can customize your exception classes (i.e.: an `InputException` like in your example), and you can still throw them if necessary, like in AJAX requests and such.

Hope this helps!

Comment: good code. since you don't say why, stacking is best so the user doesn't fix one issue only to be told there's another issue, but can fix both at once (if more than one input problem exists)

Comment: @zanlok: Indeed, forgot to mention it. Thanks!